# Using AWS Lambda and WSO2 to Open Up REST APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am working on a solution in which I plan to use AWS Lambda for creating the microservices part. Amazon does not offer its API Gateway services in the region that I am going to deploy this and thus I am planning to use a non AWS API Gateway eg: WSO2 or something else as the API gateway.

I'd like to know whether the combincation of AWS Lambda and any non AWS API Gateway plays well or AWS Lambda require AWS API Gateway for this kind of solution?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I'm curious, what region are you going to deploy in? API Gateway is available in every region that Lambda is available in.

Comment: @Jack Kohn - AWS the location is Sydney

Comment: According to this Lambda isn't available in Sydney? https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

Comment: @Mark B No it is not; infact both Lambda and API gateway is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager is not integrated to the AWS Lambda event architecture. So automatic code triggering would not be available out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 API Manager v3.1+ supports AWS Lambda functions. You can find more details in https://medium.com/@binod.16/wso2-api-manager-v3-1-supports-aws-lambda-functions-9e24752b5abb